# How to bind object of data in html page in angular2

Tags: angular

In `userdata` I have got `firstname` , `lastname`.... So I want to bind `firstname` in homecomponent.html, so how can I bind it in html template ?

```
export class HomeComponent {

    constructor(private authenticationService : AuthenticationService) {
        userdata=this.authenticationService.user_data;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are getting as `userdata` have you tried to console it? If yes then what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're discussing interpolation you can show any field of the `userdata` object you can do this in your html:

```
<p>{{userdata.firstname}} {{userdata.lastname}}</p>
```

Comment: show error: home.component.html:19 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (home.component.html:22)

Comment: It depends on what are the fields of your user data. Try console logging `userdata` after you assign the value to see what the field names are.

Answer (score 1):

Just,

```
<div><h1>{{userdata.firstname}}</h1></div>
```

**EDIT:**

if your data comes from an asynchrnous call, then use elvis operator to check the value exists,

```
<div><h1>{{userdata?.firstname}}</h1></div>
```

Comment: show error: home.component.html:19 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (home.component.html:22)

Comment: try using elvis operator like this <div><h1>{{userdata?.firstname}}</h1></div>

Comment: can you please explain me about it brief

Comment: yaah sure but its show wait for 5 minute I will mark after 5 minute

Comment: what do you want me to explain?

Comment: It's called `Safe Navigation Operator`.

Comment: I want to know about elvis operator

Comment: The safe navigation operator (?) means that the employer field is optional and if undefined, the rest of the expression should be ignored

Comment: after use of this if I change other code in html then its working stop. So i need to every time signout from the my page and refresh the page then its working again any solution ?

Comment: why did u remove the answer