# How to bind object of data in html page in angular2 but facing issue after reload

Tags: angular

I used this method for binding but when I reload the page its working stop

```
<div><h1>{{userdata?.firstname}}</h1></div> 

export class HomeComponent {

    constructor(private authenticationService : AuthenticationService) {
        userdata=this.authenticationService.user_data;
    }
}
```

Comment: What actually is your concern? Can you post your code

Comment: a LOT of code is missing. First of all, do you have a component ?

Comment: As I mentioned in the previous question, try logging your userdata after you assigned it in your constructor. All the `?` (elvis operator) does is ensure that the object exists, then it'll go for the sub object. It's important to see what's in your object as it may not have the right field, or your `authenticationService` may not be returning anything.

Comment: Also, can we see the code for the `authenticationService`?

Comment: but its working every time before reload the page

Comment: authentication service code is too long so not able to post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind object of data in html page in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644893/how-to-bind-object-of-data-in-html-page-in-angular2)

Comment: Well, let me keep it simple, are you restoring the cached user object? And if so, is it happening in time? Restoring from the cache would be asynchronous, so it could still be happening when you refresh the page and then call the service for the details. If that's the case you may want to store the user object in an observable and subscribe to that rather than just the static field. That way when the user is restored you can subscribe to the changed and show it in your template.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo definitely related, but it's a different issue. Not sure how to handle that, just saying is all.

Comment: can you explain in terms of code ??

Comment: Writing a quick and dirty example as an answer. hold on....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service could look something like this...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  private _user_data: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  constructor() {
    this._restoreUser()
  }

  get user_data(): Observable<any> {
    return this._user_data.asObservable();
  }

  private _restoreUser(): void {
    let user: any;
    // use any code to restore user from cache and assign it to the scoped user variable
    this._user_data.next(user);
  }
}
```

And in your home component...

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public userdata: any;
  private _userdataSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._userdataSub = this.authenticationService.user_data.subscribe((userdata) => {
      this.userdata = userdata;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._userdataSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```